# Plotly JS charts with dual category axis

Tags: bar-chart, plotly

I am trying to add second category to x axis so that it looks like a grouped by category.
The sample provided by plotly doesn't show this option. Has anyone tried the dual category

```
var trace1 = {
  x: ['A12', 'BC2', 109, '12F', 215, 304],
  y: [1, 6, 3, 5, 1, 4],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'bar',
  name: 'Team A',
 text: ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Peaches', 'Bananas', 'Pineapples',     Cherries'],
};

var data = [ trace1 ];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
  type: 'category',
  title: 'Product Code',
 },
yaxis: {
range: [0, 7],
title: 'Number of Items in Stock'
},
title:'Inventory'
};

Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

https://plot.ly/javascript/axes/

Desired result (Sample Image) -

[image: Sample Image]